# What is the difference in various ways of  defining a script?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

What is the difference in various ways of  defining a script?

The ways I am talking about is this

1. `<script>....</script>`
2. `<script language="javascript">.....</script>`
3. `<script type="text/javascript">...........</script>`

Since, they all do same things, what is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), `type` attribute is required, and determines script language, whereas `language` attribute (which does more or less the same) is deprecated in favor of `type`, so you should use `type` attribute.

Comment: I am rather asking about the difference than which is preferred? Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

> `<script language="javascript">`

[HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#script) — The first attempt

> `<script type="text/javascript">`

[HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) and [XHTML 1.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#abstract) — using MIME types for everything. **This is the current standard. Use this.**

> `<script>`

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script) (draft) — "Ah, too many authors don't care, browsers error recover from it anyway, lets all but give up on the possibility other other embedded scripting languages being used"

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 4.01 the type attribute is required. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT

In practice though, all commonly used browsers default this to text/javascript, so there isn't really a need to specify it unless you care about validators or older versions of IE. The HTML5 spec makes it optional. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#attr-script-type